# Populating a table based on partial match of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, html-table

I have an XML Doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="guitarsXSLStyleSheet.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<guitars>
    <guitar>
        <model>Strat</model>
        <year>1978</year>
        <price>2500</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Jaguar</model>
        <year>2006</year>
        <price>400</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Strat</model>
        <year>2015</year>
        <price>900</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Tele</model>
        <year>1981</year>
        <price>1200</price>
    </guitar>
</guitars>
```

And I have an XSL stylesheet which transforms those values in to a table, plucking out only the guitars where the model is a strat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table id="guitarTable" border="1" width="200">
            <tr class="header">
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//guitar[model = 'Strat']"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="guitar">
        <tr>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="model" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="year" />  </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now in reality for the XSL doc, I'm inserting the `[model = 'Strat']` via jquery in a separate HTML document based on user input (maybe the user types "Strat", maybe they type "Jaguar", the resulting table forms itself based on this), but I'm looking more for the base level explanation here at this simplified level.

I'm thinking of trying to get at the model names on a partial completion of the user's search and I want to use the function `contains(string, string)`

I though of replacing: `select="//guitar[model = 'Strat']"` in my XSL with

`select="//guitar/model[contains(., 'Stra')]"`

But this bungs up the resulting table, just keeping the header row and returning a single "unboxed" row that just says "StratStrat".

Any ideas? I would ideally keep the use of the "contains" method in here in some way, I think I'm messing up the Xpath. Or perhaps it needs to be in the template match section of the xsl? Thanks!

Comment: Your template matches `guitar`, so try `select="//guitar[contains(model, 'Stra')]"`. P.S. `//` is expensive - replace it with the exact path.

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Wish you had put this as an answer so I could check it as correct.

Comment: As you wish. ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I though of replacing: `select="//guitar[model = 'Strat']"` in my XSL
>   with
>
> ```
> select="//guitar/model[contains(., 'Stra')]"
> ```

Since your template matches `guitar`, you need to apply templates to `guitar` too, not to its child `model`:

```
select="//guitar[contains(model, 'Stra')]"
```

---

P.S. `//` is expensive - replace it with the exact path, e.g:

```
select="guitars/guitar[contains(model, 'Stra')]"
```